# How to create Responsive Table with Search Feature on theme?

Tags: wordpress

We have built a web-site using twentysixteen wordpress theme.

I need a search box to search a responsive table. The below table works fine with search..

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Html-Table-Live-Search/

Now i tried to use a responsive table and provide the above search which doesn't work in the above theme

i tried the following responsive tables

http://exisweb.net/responsive-tables-in-wordpress

The table is responsive but unable to provide a search on the table.

1. How to provide a search for the above responsive table?
2. How to provide a fastest search like above where the table has nearly 2000 rows with seven columns?

Thanks in advance.

Data Table doesn't seems to work in twenty sixteen wordpress theme

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.3/dt-1.10.12/r-2.1.0/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-2.2.3/dt-1.10.12/r-2.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY: 300,
        paging: false
    } );
    } );

```
<style>
div.container { max-width: 1200px }
</style>
</head>

<table id="example" class="display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" 
width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger</td>
            <td>Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett</td>
            <td>Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
            <td>8422</td>
            <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton</td>
            <td>Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
            <td>1562</td>
            <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric</td>
            <td>Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
            <td>6224</td>
            <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi</td>
            <td>Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
            <td>5407</td>
            <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brielle</td>
            <td>Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
            <td>4804</td>
            <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Herrod</td>
            <td>Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
            <td>9608</td>
            <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rhona</td>
            <td>Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$327,900</td>
            <td>6200</td>
            <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Colleen</td>
            <td>Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>
            <td>2360</td>
            <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sonya</td>
            <td>Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
            <td>1667</td>
            <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jena</td>
            <td>Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
            <td>3814</td>
            <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quinn</td>
            <td>Flynn</td>
            <td>Support Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$342,000</td>
            <td>9497</td>
            <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Charde</td>
            <td>Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$470,600</td>
            <td>6741</td>
            <td>c.marshall@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Haley</td>
            <td>Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$313,500</td>
            <td>3597</td>
            <td>h.kennedy@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tatyana</td>
            <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>2010/03/17</td>
            <td>$385,750</td>
            <td>1965</td>
            <td>t.fitzpatrick@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Silva</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2012/11/27</td>
            <td>$198,500</td>
            <td>1581</td>
            <td>m.silva@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paul</td>
            <td>Byrd</td>
            <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2010/06/09</td>
            <td>$725,000</td>
            <td>3059</td>
            <td>p.byrd@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gloria</td>
            <td>Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2009/04/10</td>
            <td>$237,500</td>
            <td>1721</td>
            <td>g.little@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bradley</td>
            <td>Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$132,000</td>
            <td>2558</td>
            <td>b.greer@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dai</td>
            <td>Rios</td>
            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$217,500</td>
            <td>2290</td>
            <td>d.rios@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jenette</td>
            <td>Caldwell</td>
            <td>Development Lead</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$345,000</td>
            <td>1937</td>
            <td>j.caldwell@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yuri</td>
            <td>Berry</td>
            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$675,000</td>
            <td>6154</td>
            <td>y.berry@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Caesar</td>
            <td>Vance</td>
            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$106,450</td>
            <td>8330</td>
            <td>c.vance@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Doris</td>
            <td>Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$85,600</td>
            <td>3023</td>
            <td>d.wilder@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Angelica</td>
            <td>Ramos</td>
            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$1,200,000</td>
            <td>5797</td>
            <td>a.ramos@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin</td>
            <td>Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$92,575</td>
            <td>8822</td>
            <td>g.joyce@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer</td>
            <td>Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$357,650</td>
            <td>9239</td>
            <td>j.chang@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brenden</td>
            <td>Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$206,850</td>
            <td>1314</td>
            <td>b.wagner@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fiona</td>
            <td>Green</td>
            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$850,000</td>
            <td>2947</td>
            <td>f.green@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shou</td>
            <td>Itou</td>
            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$163,000</td>
            <td>8899</td>
            <td>s.itou@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michelle</td>
            <td>House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$95,400</td>
            <td>2769</td>
            <td>m.house@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suki</td>
            <td>Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$114,500</td>
            <td>6832</td>
            <td>s.burks@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Prescott</td>
            <td>Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$145,000</td>
            <td>3606</td>
            <td>p.bartlett@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin</td>
            <td>Cortez</td>
            <td>Team Leader</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$235,500</td>
            <td>2860</td>
            <td>g.cortez@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Martena</td>
            <td>Mccray</td>
            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$324,050</td>
            <td>8240</td>
            <td>m.mccray@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unity</td>
            <td>Butler</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/12/09</td>
            <td>$85,675</td>
            <td>5384</td>
            <td>u.butler@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Howard</td>
            <td>Hatfield</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/12/16</td>
            <td>$164,500</td>
            <td>7031</td>
            <td>h.hatfield@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hope</td>
            <td>Fuentes</td>
            <td>Secretary</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$109,850</td>
            <td>6318</td>
            <td>h.fuentes@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vivian</td>
            <td>Harrell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$452,500</td>
            <td>9422</td>
            <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Timothy</td>
            <td>Mooney</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$136,200</td>
            <td>7580</td>
            <td>t.mooney@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$645,750</td>
            <td>1042</td>
            <td>j.bradshaw@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Olivia</td>
            <td>Liang</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$234,500</td>
            <td>2120</td>
            <td>o.liang@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruno</td>
            <td>Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$163,500</td>
            <td>6222</td>
            <td>b.nash@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sakura</td>
            <td>Yamamoto</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$139,575</td>
            <td>9383</td>
            <td>s.yamamoto@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thor</td>
            <td>Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$98,540</td>
            <td>8327</td>
            <td>t.walton@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finn</td>
            <td>Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$87,500</td>
            <td>2927</td>
            <td>f.camacho@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Serge</td>
            <td>Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$138,575</td>
            <td>8352</td>
            <td>s.baldwin@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zenaida</td>
            <td>Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$125,250</td>
            <td>7439</td>
            <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zorita</td>
            <td>Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$115,000</td>
            <td>4389</td>
            <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer</td>
            <td>Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$75,650</td>
            <td>3431</td>
            <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cara</td>
            <td>Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$145,600</td>
            <td>3990</td>
            <td>c.stevens@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hermione</td>
            <td>Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
            <td>1016</td>
            <td>h.butler@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lael</td>
            <td>Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
            <td>6733</td>
            <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jonas</td>
            <td>Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$86,500</td>
            <td>8196</td>
            <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shad</td>
            <td>Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
            <td>6373</td>
            <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
            <td>5384</td>
            <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna</td>
            <td>Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
            <td>4226</td>
            <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Check the datatables plugin https://datatables.net/

Comment: is the datatables plugin is opensource/free or payable?

Comment: Can you please help me with a sample code?

Comment: datatables plugin is free.

Comment: Check the link https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Comment: How to download and create the exact table like the sample. I need all the files which are required and run the sample as shown in web-site. the downloaded file doesn't show up properly. i have posted this question in datatable forum too. https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36484/the-example-provided-in-the-responsive-sample-doesnt-work-for-me-any-help?new=1 please kindly help me on this to resolve

Comment: Hey @SamuelK, you should accpet an answer ( and upvote if you like ) and comment on the answer if it doesn't solve the issue for you... Click the tick mark below voting up down arrows besides an answer. Up arrow to upvote 

Comment: This is how other people know if the question is solved :)

Comment: The problem is not resolved still exist..locally works fine but doesn't work when placed inside word press page

Answer (score 0):

Check this Html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>

<body>
    <table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sites</th>
                <th>Sites2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
                <td>SitePoint</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#example").dataTable();
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#tablename').DataTable({

```
        "sDom": "Tft<'row DTTTFooter'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
        "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']],
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [5, 15, 20, -1],
            [5, 15, 20, "All"]
        ],
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [

            ],
            "sSwfPath": "assets/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            { "className": "dt-body-center", "targets": "_all" },

         {
             "targets": [7],
             "visible": false,
             "searchable": false
         }
        ],
        "autoWidth": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "language": {
            "sEmptyTable": "No service request found.",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": "Prev",
                "sNext": "Next"
            }
        },
        bProcessing: true,
```

use this configuration attributes to achieve functionality you want

Comment: Naveen, can you please help me with the full html